# All HTML5 structural elements?

Tags: html, structure, element

I'm sorry for bothering you, but can you tell me (or just copy) all html5 structural elements, I'm googling but there is information only about new html5 elements, old one are excluded. And when i googled HTML structural elements, every site write different elements. I have to write about html5 structural elements for exam in my school.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if question is stupid, i just need to know basic elements and structural. Im totally newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might want to take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Content_sectioning) - the documentation on `Element` by the Mozilla Developer Network.

It looks like they did miss one (as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30800108/4633828) by cezar) in that list though, [`aside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside). Somebody should fix that. ;)

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) also would probably be probably interesting to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link from the World Wide Web Consortium Wiki:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements

According to it the old structural elements of HTML are:

- `div`
- `span`

and the new ones from HTML5 are:

- `header`
- `footer`
- `nav`
- `article`
- `section`
- `aside`

I hope this helps you.

Comment: And this: doctype
html
head
title
base
link
meta
style
script
noscript

Comment: What do you mean by structural? I gave you a list of elements that for the most part don't _do_ anything, but rather define the structure of the page. If you wanted tags that modify how the page works, check out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Document_metadata).

Comment: I can't think of `doctype` like structural element. Headings (`h1` to `h6`), paragraph `p`, lists `ul` and `ol` can be also considered as structural elements, among many others. And don't forget `body`. Pozdrav!

Comment: Ah. I guess we all have different definitions. :) I consider structural elements any element that does not have an effect (or has a small effect) on the formatting of the page. If that element changes how the contents of itself looks, I'd consider it a formatting element (for example, `i`, `p`, `ul`, etc.).